# Values from returned bundle are always 0

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, bundle

I am working on an app with 3 activites.  Activity 3 opens from 2, and 2 opens from 1.  I would like to get two numbers that the user enters in activity 3 and handle them in activity 2.

This is the code I am currently using in activity 3 to bundle my numbers to be returned to #2:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("param1", num1);
    bundle.putInt("param2", num2);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtras(bundle);

    setResult(ACTIVITY_END, i);


    finish();
}
```

And then in Activity #2:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int num1 = bundle.getInt("param1"));
    int num2 = bundle.getInt("param2");
    //do something with ints
}
```

However, no matter what numbers are sent from #3 to #2, num1 and num2 are always 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You should put params directly in the intent

```
i.putExtra("param1", num1);
i.putExtra("param2", num2)
```

to retrieve these values use

```
int param1 = intent.getIntExtra("param1", -1);
```

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind me asking, how do I then get those numbers from in my second activity?  The Intent class doesn't seem to have any methods for getting integers with a key, and trying to use a Bundle seems to just crash the program.

Answer (score 3):

Try this user,
@Override

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("param1", num1);
    bundle.putInt("param2", num2);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("my_bundle", bundle);

    setResult(ACTIVITY_END, i);

    finish();
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("my_bundle");
    int num1 = bundle.getInt("param1"));
    int num2 = bundle.getInt("param2");
    //do something with ints
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was was assuming that onPause would be called when I hit the back button, which explains crashing I was getting.  Changed onPause to onBackPressed, probably should have mentioned I was using the back button.  Thanks again though

Comment: glad to help, best wishes, serkan